# Differential equation 3rd order

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having some trouble wrapping up a problem and could really use some assistance. The problem I'm supposed to solve is this 3rd order differential equation.

$x^3y'''-3x^2y''+6xy'-6y=0$

After substituting $y=x^\alpha$ I managed to get it to a nice form:
$\alpha^3 - 6\alpha^2+11\alpha-6 = 0$, which one can then factor out and get that $\alpha \in \{1, 2, 3\}$. What I don't understand is how to construct a solution from that result. The book we're using doesn't quite describe it properly.

I was surprised that Wolfram gives me a solution to this problem and its solution would be $C_1 \cdot x + C_2 \cdot x^2 + C_3 \cdot x^3$, but I would really appreciate an explanation of it, since I don't quite grasp why it is so.

Many thanks for your continued help and support!

Edit: Once again, sorry for getting the answer mixed up. I've fixed it now. The part I'm confused about is how did we get to the $x$, $x^2$ and $x^3$ from the three alphas. Is it simply because of the $y = x^\alpha$ substitution that was used, or is there a more in-depth reasoning that I'm missing?

Comment: i think you obtain wrong solution it must be $C_1 \cdot x + C_2 \cdot x^2+ C_3 \cdot x^3$, you get it when beck to your substituting.

Comment: Also known as a Cauchy-Euler or equidimensional differential equation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is a homogeneous linear equation, a linear combination of solutions is an equation.  You know the three linearly independent solutions
$x$, $x^2$, $x^3$, therefore $c_1 x + c_2 x^2 + c_3 x^3$ is a solution for arbitrary $c_1, c_2, c_3$.  Since this is third order, the space of solutions has dimension $3$, so that's your general solution.

I don't know how you asked Wolfram to solve this DE, but apparently you gave it the wrong equation.

Comment: Terribly sorry, I somehow managed to find a similar answer while scanning my notes and copied that instead. That's however the one that I'm referring to. How do I get to the $x$, $x^2$ and $x^3$?

Comment: You found that $ y = x^\alpha$ is a solution when $\alpha \in \{1,2,3\}$.  $\alpha = 1$ is $y=x$, $\alpha = 2$ is $y=x^2$, $\alpha=3$ is $y = x^3$.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot put a screen copy in the comments section, so I put it into the answer section, but this is not an answer.

Comment : WolframAlpha gives the correct solution if the equation is correctly typed.

[image]

Comment: Whoops, my apologies, I copied down the wrong answer from my notebook. That was indeed the one that I was referring to.